# How to create multiple fields of the same name and get its' values when submitting in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, forms, module, submit, drupal-8

Below is the configuration Form of my custom module in Drupal 8.

```
<?php
 namespance Drupal\hello_world\Form;

 class MailForm extends ConfigFormBase {

   public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

     $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

     $form['email_address'] = [
       '#type' => 'email',
       '#title' => $this->t(
         'Email address:'
       ),
     ];

     return $form;
   }

   public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

     $email_address = $form_state->getValue('email_address');

   }
 }
```

How do I create multiple input fields of the same name as following in Drupal 8?

```
<input name="email_address[]" type="email" />
<input name="email_address[]" type="email"  />
<input name="email_address[]" type="email" />
```

How can I get all the values from the above input fields as following when submitting in Drupal 8?

```
array(
  'email_address' => array(
    '0' => 'a@email.com',
    '1' => 'b@email.com',
    '2' => 'c@email.com',
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two-level array and use `'#tree' => TRUE` option:

```
$form['email_address'] = [
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#tree' => TRUE,
  '#title' => $this->t('Email address:'),
  '0' => [
    '#type' => 'email',
    '#title' => $this->t('First'),
  ],
  '1' => [
    '#type' => 'email',
    '#title' => $this->t('First'),
  ],
];
```

The only thing I'm not completely sure of (as I haven't checked this code) is the numeric indexes for email elements. Please post a comment if it is working. And if not - use strings.

Comment: How to get the values of these inputs when submitting the form?

Comment: $form_state->getValue('email_address') should return an array of values